# APEX - Error Returning SQL Query with Date from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle-apex

I am new to using APEX PL/SQL and apologise in advance if my question has been covered already.  I believe have searched exhasutively for an answer.

I have a standard query that works exactly as it should as a source for a region, but requires conversion to PL/SQL so I can process an LOV returned from a shuttle I am going to add.

This is the critical part of the working query:

```
select METRIC_DEFINITION_ID,
      METRIC_NAME,
      sum(decode(START_DATE, '01-JUN-12', VALUE)) as "Jun 2012"

from ... (a substantial query that works)
```

When I attempt to return this from a PL/SQL block:

```
BEGIN
return 'select METRIC_DEFINITION_ID,
      METRIC_NAME,
      sum(decode(START_DATE, ' '01-JUN-12' ', VALUE)) as "Jun 2012"

      from ... (a substantial query that works)';
END;
```

I receive the error message:

```
(ORA-06550: line 9, column 33: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "01-JUN-12" 
when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < ...
```

as if the compiler is expecting an operator.

I have tried

```
...TO_DATE(' '01-JUN-12' ')...
```

with no success.  Passing the string to a variable and returning that makes no difference either.

All the documentation I have read suggests my original should work.

Does anyone know if there is different syntax for 'decode' in this context (APEX source for a region), or am I missing something glaringly obvious here?

All suggestions appreciated.

Cheers,
Jason

===========

Adding the complete query, as requested.  Note the line

```
and METRIC_COLLECTION.METRIC_COLLECTION_ID IN :P44_COLLECTION_SELECTOR)
```

currently only works if a single item is selelcted in the shuttle named P44_COLLECTION_SELECTOR, hence the need to learn PL/SQL.

Dates will be based on inputs in the long run - this is a POC.

```
select
METRIC_DEFINITION_ID,
   METRIC_NAME,
   sum(decode(START_DATE, '01-JUN-12', VALUE)) as "Jun 2012",
   sum(decode(START_DATE, '01-JUL-12', VALUE)) as "Jul 2012",
   sum(decode(START_DATE, '01-AUG-12', VALUE)) as "Aug 2012",
   sum(decode(START_DATE, '01-SEP-12', VALUE)) as "Sep 2012",
   sum(decode(START_DATE, '01-OCT-12', VALUE)) as "Oct 2012",
   sum(decode(START_DATE, '01-NOV-12', VALUE)) as "Nov 2012"

from

(select  
METRIC_DEFINITION.METRIC_DEFINITION_ID as METRIC_DEFINITION_ID,
 METRIC_DEFINITION.METRIC_NAME as METRIC_NAME,
 METRIC_VALUE.START_DATE as START_DATE,
 METRIC_VALUE.VALUE as VALUE 
from     
METRIC_VALUE METRIC_VALUE,
 METRIC_DEFINITION METRIC_DEFINITION 
where   
METRIC_DEFINITION.METRIC_DEFINITION_ID=METRIC_VALUE.METRIC_DEFINITION_ID) 

where METRIC_DEFINITION_ID IN 

(select  
METRIC_COLLECTION_MAP.METRIC_DEFINITION_ID as METRIC_DEFINITION_ID 
from     METRIC_COLLECTION_MAP METRIC_COLLECTION_MAP,
 METRIC_COLLECTION METRIC_COLLECTION 
where
METRIC_COLLECTION.METRIC_COLLECTION_ID=METRIC_COLLECTION_MAP.METRIC_COLLECTION_ID 

and 
METRIC_COLLECTION.METRIC_COLLECTION_ID IN :P44_COLLECTION_SELECTOR)

group by METRIC_DEFINITION_ID, METRIC_NAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you put spaces in between you quotes?

Try changing:

```
sum(decode(START_DATE, ' '01-JUN-12' ', VALUE))
```

To:

```
sum(decode(START_DATE, ''01-JUN-12'', VALUE))
```

I Figure this because:

```
execute immediate 'select to_date(' '01-JUN-12' ') from dual';
```

returns the same error.

Comment: Thanks, but ' ' is the correct syntax, from what I have read. Error message changes to : ORA-06550: line 6, column 32: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "01" when expecting one of following...

Comment: In order to escape an apostrophe, there cannot be a space in between the ''; it must follow immediately or Oracle assumes the string has ended.

Comment: I would have thought the compiler would read:  return 'select ... sum(decode(START_DATE, '    as a string, then encounter '01-JUN-12'.  I have found many APEX PL/SQL examples similar to:  v_somevar := 'a string ' 'a string needing to be bounded with single quotes' ' the rest of the string';   but I haven't found an example using a date.

Comment: Can you post the substantial query that works? v_somevar := 'a string' 'a string'; will cause an error. The examples were misleading. They meant to include the concatenation operator || like this: v_somevar := 'a string' || 'a string';

Comment: Ok - I see where you are coming from. So how do I convince the PL/SQL compiler to return a string that needs to have the apostrophes in it? I'm not trying to concatenate (obviously!), but need to have the returned query inculde the apostrophes around the date. Have posted the full query as an edit to my original post.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about this one. One thing, place Quotation Marks around the aliases in the substantial query (needed if there is a space in the alias string) like you did in the critical part of the working query, and make sure to not have any spaces between the two apostrophes if you want to escape one.

Comment: BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Matthew''s String'); END; / will return "Matthew's String" (without the double quotation marks of course)

Comment: Nerg - I stripped out the quotation marks that the APEX query builder inserts in an attempt to make my post more readable - didn't think of the alias ones being taken out as well.  What is returned by: BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Matthew says ''String!'''); END; - Wanting "Matthew says 'String!'"

Comment: BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Matthew says ''String!'''); END; returns what you wanted: "Matthew says 'String!'". Do you have SQL*Plus Developer ?

Comment: You have solved my problem for me! I have no idea why it is working now and wasn't before, but you were bang on the money with the apostrophes. Thanks for your time and apologies for dragging it out further than was necessary.  (I don't have SQL*Plus Dev, btw)

Comment: No worries: I was motivated to reach 50 reputation points so I can comment on people's questions! SQLDeveloper is good for syntactical errors that APEX won't show you online.

Comment: @user1964553 (&Matthew) So in case you weren't aware: in oracle sql a double single quote means an escaped single quote, exactly so you could put one inside a string. Strings are always opened with a single quote, and closed with one. An escaped quote (thus, double single quote) will not close the string, but put the actual character in it. Also check [this documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#sthref336), and note how there is a mechanism to make life easier once you have more complicated strings :`q'!I'm a string, you're a string.!'`